# Prevent Simultaneous reads of rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a callback mechanism in place which basically gets a row from the table given a matching criteria, do some operation and based on delete flag in the row record delete that row.

The issue is that there can be multiple concurrent callbacks with the same matching criteria in this system. What I want to achieve that is, in the first callback, when I select the row for processing (based on delete flag this row may be deleted or not after processing), I want other callbacks to wait. In other words, I want to have a read lock on the row of the table and if indeed therow gets deleted in the first callback, second callback has nothing to do and it should pass.

I am using JDBC here to do these operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `for update` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55370) to lock the rows you select. A second session trying to retrieve the same rows - which also has a `for update` - will by default block until you release the locks, by committing or rolling back.

So session 1 does:

```
select column1, column2, ... from your_table where ... for update;
```

and can process the results. While it's doing that session 2 also does:

```
select column1, column2, ... from your_table where ... for update;
```

but this will now block until session 1 releases the locks.

As a simple demo, lets have a small table:

```
create table t42 (id number, delete_flag varchar2(1));
insert into t42 values (1, 'N');
insert into t42 values (2, 'N');
insert into t42 values (3, 'Y');

commit;
```

In session 1:

```
SQL> select * from t42 where delete_flag = 'Y' for update;

        ID D
---------- -
         2 Y
         3 Y
```

In session 2:

```
SQL> select * from t42 where delete_flag = 'Y' for update;
```

... which just sits there waiting.

Back in session 1, delete one of the rows that your processing would:

```
SQL> delete from t42 where id = 2;

1 row deleted.
```

Session 2 is still waiting. Lets say for some reason you only want to delete that one row and leave the other one there, so that callback transaction is complete. Now in session 1:

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Immediately session 2 now reports:

```
        ID D
---------- -
         3 Y
```

When the locks are released the query is re-executed, so it sees the current committed data, not the (locked) data that existed when the command was submitted.

Session 2 now has the lock on that row, and other sessions will still be blocked waiting for *that* session to commit or roll back. If session 1 had deleted both of the rows it had locked, session 2 would see 'no rows selected' and would have no row locks (though it would still be preventing the table being dropped or truncated).

This isn't exactly a *read* lock - other sessions can still query the table, including the locked rows, as long as they do no have the `for update` clause. But as long as all your callbacks are doing the same thing they should behave as you want.

Comment: According to my sources "for update" does not lock other reads. I have tried this myself, and other threads could read the same rows (also using for update).

It also says here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_row_locks_vs_table_locks.htm
"A writer of data does not block a reader of data"

Comment: @HolgerL - correct, selecting `for update` won't prevent other sessions reading those rows. That's what the last pargraph says? It will prevent other sessions selecting the same rows `for update` though, until the locks are released. (The other session can decide whether to wait or fail, or indeed to skip the locked rows).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [Select For Update Cursor](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/for_update.php).
The first reader will block the others (if you include NOWAIT clause the other session won't wait)